# To refresh a listview in a form from a button click in another form

Tags: c#, .net

I have two form F1 and F2. In F1 i have a listview and a add button.When i click add button F2 opens and i can add some values.

I have a button accept in F2 which when pressed add values from F2 to a table and closes F2.

I have a refresh method written for refreshing the list view in F1. i tried to call this method in the accept button_click event of F2 ..i wrote something like this in F2.cs

```
F1 f=new F1();
private void accept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //my adding values code

    this.Close();
    f.refresh();
 }
```

the refresh method is working correctly..it's just that when i call it from F2 it is not performing its function..anyone kindly suggest a better way to achieve what i want..any kind of suggestion is highly appreciated..

Comment: What is "f"? What is in your refresh call?

Comment: @dotnet_noob `f` is a new form and is not referencing the parent form.

Comment: Since you are going to close F2 after clicking the accept button, why not just create a public list in F2 to expose its values to F1 , then call refresh from F1?

Comment: @bug f is a new instance of F1 i created in F2 to use it to call a method in F1..in refresh() i have code that will load the ListView in F1 form.

Comment: Right so "f" is not the same as the Form1 you were looking at, hence you wont see it update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass reference to F1 into F2 form.

```
F2 f = new F2(this);
f.Show();
```

After this Create a Global object of f1 in forrm f2

```
 f1 GBobjF1=null;
```

Then Initialize that object GBobjF1 in following contructor of f2 form

```
 public f2(f1  f1Obj)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GBobjF1 = f1Obj;

    }
```

Now can use that Global object GBobjF1 on  f2 form,With this object you can access all public members of f1 form.
 You can refill that list view which is inside f1 Like:

```
GBobjF1.FillListView();
```

It will refresh and refill that list view with the new values

Comment: F2 f=new F2(this); i got error in this line saying that 'this' is not available in the current context..

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass reference to F1 into F2 form.

In F1 form

```
F2 f = new F2();
f.f1ref = this;
```

In F2 form

```
public F1 f1ref;

private void accept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//my adding values code
f1ref.refresh();
this.Close(); 
}
```